# Ubuntu 21.10 Color Problem on HDMI and DP

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, 21.10

I use two monitor (one on DP one on HDMI) on my MSI Ge76 Laptop. I use Ubuntu 21.10 with Windows as dual boot. My kernel: `5.16.0-12.2-liquorix-amd64`. I have color problem on my monitors. When I googled about the problem, first solution I found was calibrating my monitors on Color settings. But calibrate button is disabled on my settings. After furher research, I found that I can fix it by using NVIDIA X Server Settings.

At first, I really fixed and my monitors' color was perfect. But after rebooting, my color problem came back. When I open NVIDIA X Server Settings, display goes normal for a short period of time but problem comes back after like 15-20 seconds. And I even don't know what is the problem and how can I fixed. Any help or advice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to "Night Mode". After disabling this feature, the color settings worked as expected.